# How to get the font information from itext to use in SharpFont?

Tags: c#, itext, opentk

I'm trying rendering text get from pdf file using iText7.
I use OpenTK to render graphics, and use SharpFont to convert font file to bitmap data.

The constructor of SharpFont.Face used to convert to bitmap, needs font data for arguments as file full path or raw byte array loaded from file.

The PdfFont.fontProgram instance seems to has embedded stream named "fontFile" (using debugging IDE), but I can not get the data.

Do you know how to get the data ?